# How can I debug a custom clang-tidy check which I have written in Windows Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019, pdb-files, clang-tidy

I have build the LLV.sln files using the debug build(all pdb and binaries are getting created). My newly written checks are in check-clang-tools project. When I apply breakpoint in one of my checks and click on local windows debugger, it does not stop on the applied breakpoint. The binaries and pdbs are created in the same build directory inside Debug folder.

I have tried adding the binary paths to the debug symbols pane inside Debug configurations but it didn't help.